# Create automatic indivisual link for MYSQL Data

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, http-post, httprequest

I creating a webpage on mobile price. On the front page i gave the visuals & model of the phone and a "details" button. which submits the id for the phone on a details.php page. It shows the data good without any problem. the link looks like this "www.eeeee.com/details.php".
But i want to show the link as "www.eeee.com/details.php?brand=nokia&id=1111". How can i do this? 
Please help me...

Comment: Change the form method to `GET` instead of `POST`.

Comment: If you're posting the data, it will not show up in the URL as that is a get. If you want to send it through on the URL, then set the method type to get on your form. `method="GET"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using simple form for doing this you can use simple get method instead of post. But if you wanna make your url manually, you need to use form like this.

```
   <form  method="get" name="MobileDetails">
  <input name="brand" id="brand" value="<?php echo $brand;?>" type="hidden">
  <input name="brid" id="brid" value="<?php echo $brandid;?>" type="hidden">
   <button type="button" name="submitButton" value="get Details" onclick="getDetails()">    
 </form>
```

and javascript for your code will be like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getDetails(){
var brand = document.getElementById('brand').value;
var brandid = document.getElementById('brid').value;
document.MobileDetails.action = 'details.php?brand='+brand+'&id='+brandid;
document.MobileDetails.submit();
}
</script>
```

you can also do this by using ajax it's totally your choice.

Comment: My code is now'''
echo "<tr><form  method='get' name='MobileDetails'>";
 echo "<td id='tdbutton'> <form  method='get' name='MobileDetails'>
  <input name='brand' id='brand' value='". $db_field['brand']."' type='hidden'>
  <input name='brid' id='brid' value='". $db_field['id']."' type='hidden'>
   <button class='button' type='button' name='submitButton' value='get Details' onclick='getDetails()'>    
 </form>   </td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 echo "</table>"; 
}</br?.......... But the button do not respond when i click. I included the JS. now whats the problem.